# Mecabで日本語を分割した結果、エラーが出る

Tags: python, python3, mecab

Mecabでこのように日本語を分割したいのですが、

```
   m = MeCab.Tagger("-d /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd")
   c = m.parse('小林製薬 ヒフミド 公式 ！本気の潤い肌には。小林製薬初回９８０円').splitlines()
   for s in c:
       print(s)
```

結果は:

```
小林製薬    名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,小林製薬,コバヤシセイヤク,コバヤシセイヤク
ヒフミド    名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,*
公式  名詞,形容動詞語幹,*,*,*,*,公式,コウシキ,コーシキ
！   記号,一般,*,*,*,*,！,！,！
本気  名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,本気,ホンキ,ホンキ
の   助詞,連体化,*,*,*,*,の,ノ,ノ
潤い  名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,潤い,ウルオイ,ウルオイ
肌   名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,肌,ハダ,ハダ
に   助詞,格助詞,一般,*,*,*,に,ニ,ニ
は   助詞,係助詞,*,*,*,*,は,ハ,ワ
。   記号,句点,*,*,*,*,。,。,。
小林製薬    名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,小林製薬,コバヤシセイヤク,コバヤシセイヤク
初回  名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,初回,ショカイ,ショカイ
９８０円    名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,980円,キュウヒャクハチジュウエン,キューヒャクハチジュウエン,[:_:3180  3148    7806]
EOS
```

どうして最後のところに`[:_:3180 3148 7806]`がでるのでしょうか？

教えていただけませんか。お願いします！

Answer (score 5):

エラーでも何でもなく、mecab-ipadic-neologdの辞書に**そう入っていて**、mecabのデフォルト出力フォーマットが「辞書に入っている素性は全部出す」だから**そう出ている**だけです。

http://taku910.github.io/mecab/dic-detail.html

> 5カラム目以降は, ユーザ定義の CSV フィールドです. 基本的に どんな内容でも CSV の許す限り追加することができます.

Comment: +1: 確かに、[seed ファイル](https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd/tree/master/seed)の中の `neologd-quantity-infreq-dict-seed.20170224.csv` の105832 行目に「９８０円」のデータがあり、`[:_:3180 3148 7806]` というフィールドも含まれていました。（ところでこれはどういう意味のフィールドなのでしょう？）

Comment: なんでしょうね……。neologdの方にissueとしてあげてもいいかもしれませんね